# location of cudaEventRecord and overlapping ops, when second kernel finishes first

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have two tasks. Both of them perform copy to device (D), and run kernel (R) operations. Tasks have different kernel runtimes. R1 takes 5 times more than R2 to complete (R1 = ~17 ms, R2 = ~3.5 ms). Kernels of the tasks perform a wait operation and I allow these kernels to run concurrently. Each copy op takes 7 ms.

I have GeForce GT 555M, CUDA 4.1, and Fedora 16.

I record start and stop times of D and R ops of each task using cudaEventRecord. I use two streams for each task. I use cudaStreamWaitEvents to synchronize between these two streams of the task. One stream is used for D op of the task, the other one is used for R op of the task. My goal is to overlap D2 with R1. I measure the overall timing of task1 and task2 to figure out whether this overlap is achieved or not.

I have two scenarios. In Scenerio1, “start R1” is placed before kernels and “start R2” is placed in between kernels. In Scenerio2, “start R1” and “start R2” are both placed before kernels.

For the given pseudo-codes below, Scenario1 and Scenerio2 does not behave the same: Although Scenerio2 fails to overlap D2 with R1, Scenerio1 succeeds to do so! So my question is: **To overlap D2 with R1, why do we have to place “start R2” between kernels (instead of before), when R2 is shorter than R1?** (Please note that, I have also tested the scenario where R1 is shorter than R2. In this case, placing "start R2" before or in between the kernels does not make a difference and in both cases, we can overlap D2 with R1. After D2 is done, we can also concurrently run R1 and R2.)

Here is the pseudo-codes for Scenario1 and 2 (I use stream1 and stream3 for task1, and use stream2 and stream4 for task2):

**Scenario1 (SUCCEEDS):**

```
start overall

start D1 on stream1
D1 on stream1
stop D1 on stream1

start D2 on stream2
D2 on stream2
stop D2 on stream2

start R1 on stream3

R1 on stream3 //longer

start R2 on stream4 // start R2 is in between kernels

R2 on stream4 //shorter

stop R2 on stream4
stop R1 on stream3

stop overall
```

**Scenario2 (FAILS):**

```
start overall

start D1 on stream1
D1 on stream1
stop D1 on stream1

start D2 on stream2
D2 on stream2
stop D2 on stream2

start R1 on stream3

start R2 on stream4 // start R2 is before kernels

R1 on stream3 //longer

R2 on stream4 //shorter

stop R2 on stream4
stop R1 on stream3

stop overall
```

The overall timing for scenarios are as follows:

Scenario1 = 24.109312

Scenario2 = 31.194496

The expected overall runtime for these scenarios is D1 + R1 = 7 + 17 = 24 (we can overlap D2 with R1 and at the same time, run R1 and R2, concurrently). Although Scenario1 succeeds to achieve this runtime, Scenerio2 fails to to do so. It is because Scenario2 cannot overlap D2 with R1. (D2 takes 7 ms and that is why the Scenario2 runtime is 24 + 7 = 31).

I also attached the CUDA code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

__global__ void wait_k(long time_clocks)
{ 
    long start_clock = clock();

    long clock_offset = 0;

    while( clock_offset < time_clocks) {
        clock_offset = clock() - start_clock;
    }
}


void shorterR2_D2_R1_Overlap()
{
float *h_A;
float *d_A, *d_C;
float *h_A2;
float *d_A2, *d_C2;


int N = 10000000;
size_t size = N * sizeof(float); 

cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_A, size);
cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_A2, size);

// Allocate vector in device memory
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A2, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C2, size);


for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
{
h_A[i] = 1;
h_A2[i] = 5;
}

cudaStream_t csStream1, csStream2, csStream3, csStream4;

cudaStreamCreate(&csStream1);
cudaStreamCreate(&csStream2);
cudaStreamCreate(&csStream3);
cudaStreamCreate(&csStream4);

//allocate vars for dummy copy 
float* h_pfDummy;
float* d_pfDummy;
size_t iMemSz = 10 * sizeof(float);
cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_pfDummy, iMemSz);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pfDummy, iMemSz);

cudaMemcpyAsync(d_pfDummy, h_pfDummy, iMemSz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, csStream1);
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_pfDummy, h_pfDummy, iMemSz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, csStream2);

//delete vars of dummy copy 
cudaFree(d_pfDummy);
cudaFreeHost(h_pfDummy);

long time_clocks = 20000000; 
long div = 5;

cudaEvent_t ceEvStart, ceEvStop; 
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStart );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStop );

//diff stream time events
cudaEvent_t ceEvStartCpyDev1, ceEvStopCpyDev1, ceEvStartKer1, ceEvStopKer1;
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStartCpyDev1 );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStopCpyDev1 );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStartKer1 );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStopKer1 );
cudaEvent_t ceEvStartCpyDev2, ceEvStopCpyDev2, ceEvStartKer2, ceEvStopKer2; 
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStartCpyDev2 );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStopCpyDev2 );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStartKer2 );
cudaEventCreate( &ceEvStopKer2 );

//Scenario1: put start R1 before kernels and start R2 between kernels
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStart, 0);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartCpyDev1, csStream1);
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, csStream1);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopCpyDev1, csStream1);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartCpyDev2, csStream2);
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_A2, h_A2, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, csStream2);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopCpyDev2, csStream2);

//insert runker1 start event before concurrent kernels
cudaStreamWaitEvent(csStream3, ceEvStopCpyDev1, 0);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartKer1, csStream3); 

wait_k<<<1,1,0,csStream3>>>(time_clocks);

//insert runker2 start event between concurrent kernels
cudaStreamWaitEvent(csStream4, ceEvStopCpyDev2, 0);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartKer2, csStream4); 

wait_k<<<1,1,0,csStream4>>>(time_clocks/div);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopKer2, csStream4);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopKer1, csStream3);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStop, 0);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

float fTim1;
cudaEventElapsedTime( &fTim1, ceEvStart, ceEvStop);
printf("Scenario1 overall runtime = %10f\n", fTim1);

//Scenario2: put start R1 before kernels and start R2 between kernels
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStart, 0);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartCpyDev1, csStream1);
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, csStream1);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopCpyDev1, csStream1);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartCpyDev2, csStream2);
cudaMemcpyAsync(d_A2, h_A2, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, csStream2);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopCpyDev2, csStream2);

//insert runker1 start event before concurrent kernels
cudaStreamWaitEvent(csStream3, ceEvStopCpyDev1, 0);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartKer1, csStream3); 

//insert runker2 start event before concurrent kernels
cudaStreamWaitEvent(csStream4, ceEvStopCpyDev2, 0);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStartKer2, csStream4); 

wait_k<<<1,1,0,csStream3>>>(time_clocks);

wait_k<<<1,1,0,csStream4>>>(time_clocks/div);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopKer2, csStream4);
cudaEventRecord(ceEvStopKer1, csStream3);

cudaEventRecord(ceEvStop, 0);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

float fTim2;
cudaEventElapsedTime( &fTim2, ceEvStart, ceEvStop);
printf("Scenario2 overall runtime = %10f\n", fTim2);

}

int main()
{
 shorterR2_D2_R1_Overlap();
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [location of cudaEventRecord and overlapping ops from different streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996748/location-of-cudaeventrecord-and-overlapping-ops-from-different-streams)

Comment: I realized that if runtime of R1 is less then runtime of R2 (R1<R2), I again have the same problems. But since this problem does not reflect on overall runtime when R1<R2, it was not obvious. Also note that answer to [location of cudaEventRecord and overlapping ops from different streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996748/location-of-cudaeventrecord-and-overlapping-ops-from-different-streams) is related, but the question is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute capabilities 1.0 - 3.0 have a single push buffer to submit work to the GPU. Work is submitted in the order of the CUDA API calls. In scenario 2 the push buffer cannot execute commands beyond *cudaStreamWaitEvent(csStream4, ceEvStopCpyDev2, 0);* until ceEvStopCpyDev2 completes.

The presentation **CUDA C/C++ Streams and Concurrency**( [pdf](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf) | [video](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrency_Jan_2012.mp4) ) contains more information on this topic. The slide *Stream Scheduling* contains more details on the issue that you have observed.

Comment: The answer to [location of cudaEventRecord and overlapping ops from different streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996748/location-of-cudaeventrecord-and-overlapping-ops-from-different-streams) is related. There is single push buffer. But to be more specific, there are two queues  (one for copy, one for execution). But even if we have two queues, when Steven's explanation is considered, in Scenario2 false serialization occurs between D2 and R1 and hence, we fail.